# Someone I've seen

Tags: riddle, rhyme

**NOTE**: This is another take on a riddle/rhyme kind of puzzle. My previous one didn't get a lot of good reception, and so I've tried to make this one not fall to the same fate. Hopefully you enjoy it.

---

For a long time, this person was running
Something that many people were watching
Pressing buttons on a stick
Lights turning on in front of them
But these lights were different
They showed a person
This person who had done countless things
with a few others
3 of them known by a certain letter
Some of the things were good, some of them were bad
Some of them I can't even mention (and I'm glad)
They've popularized things that never would have had the traction
And instead would have succumbed to abstraction
But when in doubt, and you need a quick filler:
**VERWRPGLBHEERNYVGLNAQFHOFGVGHGRZLBJA**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you...

> The Mythbusters

For a long time, this person was running
Something that many people were watching

> Adam & Jamie were "running" the show

Pressing buttons on a stick
Lights turning on in front of them

> Pressing the detonator (They're sort of famous for their explosions)

But these lights were different
They showed a person
This person who had done countless things with a few others
3 of them known by a certain letter

> The build team (Tori, Kari, & Grant)

Some of the things were good, some of them were bad
Some of them I can't even mention (and I'm glad)

> Some of their myths were good, bad, and unmentionable

They've popularized things that never would have had the traction
And instead would have succumbed to abstraction

> They made science fun!!

But when in doubt, and you need a quick filler: **VERWRPGLBHEERNYVGLNAQFHOFGVGHGRZLBJA!**

> i reject your reality and substitute my own
>
>  One of Adam Savage's catch phrases

Comment: Nice one! You got it correct!

Answer (score 1):

Is this:

> Television

VERWRPGLBHEERNYVGLNAQFHOFGVGHGRZLBJA

> This is a cipher which when encoded

Gave:

> irejectyourrealityandsubstitutemyown.

That fits with the answer:

> As it shows reality but in its own technical way.

All lines are explanable.  But some that are not i will try.

Pressing buttons on a stick

> A tv remote.

They showed a person
This person who had done countless things.

> May be any news about any criminal coming on tv.

3 of them known by a certain letter.

> I cant guess about this one.

Some of the things were good, some of them were bad
Some of them I can't even mention (and I'm glad)

> Again the news channel

They've popularized things that never would have had the traction
And instead would have succumbed to abstraction.

> Advantages of television.

Answer (score 1):

> Howling Mad Murdock?

For a long time, this person was running

> they were 'on the run'

Something that many people were watching
Pressing buttons on a stick
Lights turning on in front of them
But these lights were different

> A tv show

They showed a person
This person who had done countless things
with a few others
3 of them known by a certain letter

> the A-team

Some of the things were good, some of them were bad
Some of them I can't even mention (and I'm glad)
They've popularized things that never would have had the traction
And instead would have succumbed to abstraction

> they did lots of crazy stuff some (or most) of which literally defied the laws of physics

But when in doubt, and you need a quick filler: VERWRPGLBHEERNYVGLNAQFHOFGVGHGRZLBJA!

> i reject your reality and substitute my own - (Howling Mad Murdock was mad)